# Npgsql ERROR:42703 to use the non ascii character in a bind variable name

Tags: .net, npgsql

I get Npgsql ERROR:42703 when I use non-ASCII characters in a bind variable name.

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.CommandText = "select * from testtable where col1 = @漢字";
cmd.Parameters.Add("漢字", NpgsqlDbType.Char);
cmd.Parameters["漢字"].Value = "0";
cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

> ERROR: 42703: column "漢字" does not exist

ASCII characters (`@kanji`) have no problem.

I tried also other versions:

- Ver 3.0.7 is the same problem.
- Ver 2.2.7 is the same problem.
- Ver 2.2.0 is the same problem.
- Ver 2.0.12 is no problem.

Comment: Can you please open an issue on https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql?

Comment: Never mind opened, https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1177

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in Npgsql 3.1.6 (will be released soon).